# prove $\lim\limits_{x\to-e^{+}}(x+e)^{1/2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{e^t+xt}dt=\pi\sqrt{\frac{2}{e}}$

Tags: integration, limits

> Show that $$\lim_{x\to-e^{+}}(x+e)^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{e^t+xt}dt=\pi\sqrt{\frac{2}{e}}$$

Is this result right or wrong? If true, please prove it. Thank you,
since this integral $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{e^t+xt}dt$$ has no analytical solution

Comment: Since you've kept committing the same mistake in your last few questions: **do not use `\dfrac` in the title**; it suffices to just use `\frac`.

Comment: Are you sure $e$ in the denominator of the RHS is not $e-\frac12$?

Comment: I'm not sure,Thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite the integral as
$$I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dt}{e^t-et+(x+e)t}.$$
It is easy to check that $e^t\geq e t$ for all $t>0$ and the only point where the equality is achieved is $t=1$. Therefore the main asymptotic contribution to the integral will come from the vicinity of this point (note that $y=et$ is the tangent line to $y=e^t$ at $t=1$). Taylor expanding $$e^t-et=\frac{e}{2}(t-1)^2+O((t-1)^3)$$ and making the change of variables $t-1=\sqrt{x+e}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{2}{e}}\cdot s$, we then get
\begin{align}
I\simeq\int_{1-\Delta}^{1+\Delta}\frac{dt}{\frac{e}{2}(t-1)^2+(x+e)+\ldots}\simeq\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+e}}\sqrt{\frac{2}{e}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{ds}{ s^2+1}\simeq \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{x+e}}\sqrt{\frac{2}{e}}.
\end{align}

Comment: It's nice.Thank you my frend @O.L.